# Use Angular 8 function as a callback of an external JS script

Tags: angular, angular8

Given an Angular 8 project, external JS file loaded into the header to handle CreditCard details (it loads an inline form).

Upon 'pay' ajax request fires and the result can be logged out to the console via callback function.

Now, in regular JS we could define a function (or object) on the global scope.
and use it like

```
<script src="payment.widget.js" callback="myCallback">
```

The question would be how to define and use myCallback so the external widget can access

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `HttpClientJsonpModule`. If you add this to your `AppModule`, you can do a call like this:

```
http.jsonp('payment.widget.js', 'callback').subscribe(res => this.res = res);
```

Comment: Hi Pierre, I do not call payment.widget.js, I just pass the callback function like <script  src ="http://3rdparty.payment.widget.js" success-callback="myCallbackInAngular" > and the 3rd party should call my angular function upon success